# UITableView with collapsable headers - need to adjust autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So I have this layout

[image]

I'm using autoLayout, and initially the tableview has two sections, both of which are collapsed. The height of the tableview and surrounding views are correct.

When one of the section headers is expanded by a touch gesture, the rows appear and therefore the tableview height increases. However, at this stage, the parent view (B) doesn't grow to accommodate the extra height

I have attached an outlet to the constraint for the tableview (height >=100) and called this:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    NSLog(@"About to layout subviews");
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    CGFloat height = self.infoTableView.contentSize.height - 20.0f; 
    self.infoTableHeightConstraint.constant = height;

    NSLog(@"Set height constraint to %f",height);

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

And this works well, if I programatically call one of the section headers to open/close within viewDidLoad, however when I touch to expand/contract, the adjustment isn't made....

Any ideas on how to ensure View B's height will adjust to tableview (BTW, each row is a different height)

Comment: Why would the tableview's height change?  It's contentview's size should change, but that should have no effect on views which are siblings or parents of the tableview.

Comment: I want the height of the table view to represent the current height of the visible content within the table. So as sections are opened or collapsed the overall table height will change to accommodate the visible rows.

Comment: What happens when the content exceeds the screen height?

Comment: It's embedded within a scroll view.

Comment: Could you make the views above and below the tableview the header and footer views, respectively?  You're trying to use a tableview in a way it was never intended to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I've got this working using a few hacks:

Add an IBOutlet to the tableview height constraint (infoTableView)

Add the following method:

```
-(void)updateTableHeightConstraint{

 [self.infoTableView layoutIfNeeded];
 CGFloat height = self.infoTableView.contentSize.height - 20.0f; //- 200.0f;
 self.infoTableHeightConstraint.constant = height;

 NSLog(@"Set height constraint to %f",height);

 [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

}
```

Then call this method when

1) Tableview is initially loaded
2) Table headers are toggled

The key here was to call [self.infoTableView layoutIfNeeded] before adjusting the constraint, which ensures the table.contentSize.height is correct